# Chrome extension say that this can use at offline mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Question 1:

My Chrome extension of the Chrome store says that my plug-ins can run in offline mode but it will download and update data from json which they can not do without the internet. So how can I remove as it is not in Chrome store.

Can be run offline

Comment: And questions 2 and 3 would be?

Comment: **please** edit your question for clarity. what does 'Can be run offline' has to do with the question?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you should delete this line from your manifest file:

> "offline_enabled": true

Read about it at [code.google.com](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/offline_enabled.html)

Answer (score 0):

Extensions running in offline mode means that your extension will still work if the there is not internet connection and any changes will be queued up to sync online once a connection is established again. Since all Chrome extensions on the Web Store require a working connection to install you can safely assume that all users of your extension will be able to download initial data sets needed by  your extension.

Comment: the poster said that the app is not in the app store